# black, white and green wires from box, but only black and white on fixture

Tags: light-fixture

My wiring coming out of the electrical box are white, black and green.  How do I connect the light fixture that only has black and white?  Is there another way to connect the ground (green) wire to the fixture?  There also is not a green screw.  Thanks for the assistance.

Rick

Comment: Does the fixture have exposed metal parts, and does it have a "square-within-a-square" marking near its UL mark?

Comment: yes, most of it is exposed with the exception of the clear plastic light cover.  I don't remember seeing a UL mark.  Have to check for it in the morning

Comment: Mind taking a photo of the top of the fixture, and of the label/markings on it, and posting it here, too?